# Android security risk? /cache partition encryption

Tags: encryption, android

So I understand Android's Full Disk Encryption only encrypts the /data partition. But if the /cache partition is unencrypted, isn't that a massive security risk? As I understand it, /cache is used for storing temporary data for applications. Wouldn't there be a lot of sensitive information in the /cache partition?

For instance, let's say I lose my company phone, the browser on which had been used to access my company's website. So this phone had accessed not just my password to my company's website, but also our clients' financial information, photos, addresses, contact information, etc. While the /data partition is encrypted, did the browser temporarily store all this sensitive information, **unencrypted**, to the /cache partition? Even if the /cache is cleared after use,  any deleted information would be easily recoverable through use of any file recovery software. Even a zero-fill would not be sufficient, since that would be defeated by the wear-leveling mechanisms of flash storage.

What do you guys think? Is the /cache partition really the huge gaping hole of security that my limited understanding of Android makes it out to be?

Comment: I believe your understanding of the cache partition is incorrect: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27233
Most applications store cached information in a directory inside of their data directory, either in /data or /sdcard/Android/.